# create and send Ek(file || H(file)) in one passage

Tags: c, ssl, encryption, hash, openssl

I want to send through a socket a message encrypted in symmetric way with his hash.
If possible i want to do all with only one read on the file to be more efficient and sending data when they are ready.
I make this but i can't figure out why doesn't work:

```
    void symmetric_encrypt_send(SSL* connection, char* file_name, unsigned char* key, int key_len){

        //generic
        int ret;
        unsigned char buffer[DIM_BUFFER];
        FILE* fd;
        int readed_byte;

        //encrypt
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX* ctx;
        unsigned char ciphertex[DIM_BUFFER];
        int outlen = 0;

        //hash
        EVP_MD_CTX sha_ctx;
        unsigned int digest_size = 32;
        unsigned char hash[digest_size];

        //open file
        fd = fopen(file_name, "r");
        if(fd == NULL){
            printf("Impossible to open %s file\n", file_name);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        //encrypt initialization
        ctx = (EVP_CIPHER_CTX*)malloc(sizeof(EVP_CIPHER_CTX));  
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(ctx);
        EVP_EncryptInit(ctx, SYM_CIPHER, key, NULL);

        //hash initialization
        EVP_MD_CTX_init(&sha_ctx);
        EVP_DigestInit(&sha_ctx, EVP_sha256());

        //send dimension
        struct stat st;
        stat(file_name, &st); // file size = st.st_size
        int tmp = ((st.st_size + digest_size)/ EVP_CIPHER_block_size(SYM_CIPHER)) + 1;
        ret = secure_write(0, &tmp, sizeof(int), connection); 
        check_ret(ret, sizeof(int));

        //read until end of file
        //for each read update encrypt and hash
        while( 1 ){

            readed_byte = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), DIM_BUFFER, fd);
            if(readed_byte == -1){
                printf("Error");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            if(readed_byte == 0){   //nel caso in cui la dimensione del file è multipla di dim_buffer
                break;
            }

            //Encrypt Update
            EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, ciphertex, &outlen, buffer, readed_byte);

            //hash update
            EVP_DigestUpdate(&sha_ctx, buffer, readed_byte);

            //send encrypted data at this step
            printf("testo inviato: %.*s\n", outlen, ciphertex);
            ret = secure_write(0, ciphertex, outlen, connection); 
            check_ret(ret, outlen);

            if(readed_byte != DIM_BUFFER){
                break;
            }
        }

        //hashfinal; also clear ctx
        EVP_DigestFinal(&sha_ctx, hash, &digest_size);


        //encrypt update the hash
        EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, ciphertex, &outlen, hash, digest_size);
        ret = secure_write(0, ciphertex, outlen, connection); 
        check_ret(ret, outlen);

        //EVP_EncryptFinal(); also close ctx so no need for EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(ctx);
        ret = EVP_EncryptFinal(ctx, ciphertex, &outlen);
        if(ret == 0)
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        ret = secure_write(0, ciphertex, outlen, connection); 
        check_ret(ret, outlen);

        //close
        free(ctx);
        fclose(fd);
    }
```

where

```
    #define DIM_BUFFER 1024
    int secure_read(int fd, void* buffer, int count, SSL* sock);
    int secure_write(int fd, void* buffer, int count, SSL* sock);
```

Comment: Related, `Ek(file || H(file))` is known to be defective. See [Message Confidentiality and Integrity - Prepend Hash versus Append Hash](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sci.crypt/xsUyn3eT5PQ). That's the method specified in Handbook of Applied Cryptography, section 9.6, but we have a better understanding now. Instead, you should use an authenticated encryption mode, like EAX, CCM or GCM. For that, see [EVP Authenticated Encryption and Decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption).

Comment: Related, that "one pass" you are looking for is patented by Rogaway. Its built into [OCB mode](http://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/ocb/). Nearly everything else uses "two pass" to avoid the patent. Fortunately, Rogaway is very liberal on his licensing of the patent. I think he's [given it to SSL/TLS royalty free, and related projects like OpenSSL, GnuTLS, etc](http://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/ocb/license.htm). I think the only restriction he places is non-military.

Comment: Thanks for all the information.  I surely remember that.  But in this case I need to implement a specific protocol that I have build,  it's not strictly necessary for me to do encryption and hashing in one pass but this way is much more efficient so I don't think I'm violating some patent.